# Como formatear salida de consulta SQL Server desde NODE JS a traves de MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, mssql

Dejo un ejemplo sencillo de creación de una base de datos en `SQL Server` y una sentencia `Select` que luego uso en `NODE JS` con el pluggin `MSSQL`:

```
Create Database pruebas;

Create Table autos
             (
             id_auto Int
           , marca   VarChar(20)
           , modelo  VarChar(20)
           , Primary Key(id_auto)
             );

Create Table especificaciones
             (
             especificacion VarChar(20)
           , id_auto        Int
           , Foreign Key(id_auto) References autos(id_auto)
             );

Insert Into autos(id_auto
                , marca
                , modelo)
Values
       ( 1, 'Ford', 'Mustang' ),
       ( 2, 'Chevrolet', 'Camaro' ),
       ( 3, 'Dodge', 'Charger' );

Insert Into especificaciones
Values
       ( 'Potencia: 350 HP', 1 ),
       ( 'Velocidad: 255 km/h', 1 ),
       ( 'Cilindrada: 3500 cc', 1 ),
       ( 'Peso: 1340 Kg', 1 ),
       ( 'Potencia: 345 HP', 2 ),
       ( 'Velocidad: 250 km/h', 2 ),
       ( 'Cilindrada: 3700 cc', 2 ),
       ( 'Peso: 1580 Kg', 2 ),
       ( 'Potencia: 320 HP', 3 ),
       ( 'Velocidad: 230 km/h', 3 ),
       ( 'Cilindrada: 3900 cc', 3 ),
       ( 'Peso: 1800 Kg', 3 );


Select autos.marca
     , autos.modelo
     , especificaciones.especificacion
       From autos
            Inner Join especificaciones On autos.id_auto = especificaciones.id_auto;

--no funciona esta sentencia por contener mas de un valor

Select autos.marca
     , autos.modelo
     , (
         Select especificaciones.especificacion
                From autos
                     Inner Join especificaciones On autos.id_auto = especificaciones.id_auto
       ) As especificaciones
       From autos;

--si funciona de esta manera pero no me sirve el formato json

Select autos.marca
     , autos.modelo
     , (
         Select especificaciones.especificacion
                From autos
                     Inner Join especificaciones On autos.id_auto = especificaciones.id_auto For json Path
       ) As especificaciones
       From autos;
```

Luego con el siguiente código realizo la consulta desde `NODE JS` usando la primera sentencia select de `TSQL`:

```
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = {
user: 'sa',
password: '1234',
server: 'localhost', 
database: 'pruebas',
options: { trustServerCertificate: true }
};

let getEmbarque = async () => {
  try {
      await sql.connect(config);
      let db = new sql.Request();
      let consulta = `select autos.marca, autos.modelo, especificaciones.especificacion from autos inner join especificaciones on autos.id_auto = especificaciones.id_auto`;
      let resultado = await db.query(consulta);
      let datos = resultado;
      return datos;
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      throw err;
  }
}

getEmbarque()
.then(datos => {
  console.log(datos.recordset);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(`Hubo un error`);
});
```

con lo cual obtengo el siguiente objeto Javascript:

```
[
  {
    marca: 'Ford',
    modelo: 'Mustang',
    especificacion: 'Potencia: 350 HP'
  },
  {
    marca: 'Ford',
    modelo: 'Mustang',
    especificacion: 'Velocidad: 255 km/h'
  },
  {
    marca: 'Ford',
    modelo: 'Mustang',
    especificacion: 'Cilindrada: 3500 cc'
  },
  { marca: 'Ford', 
    modelo: 'Mustang',
    especificacion: 'Peso: 1340 Kg' },
  {
    marca: 'Chevrolet',
    modelo: 'Camaro',
    especificacion: 'Potencia: 345 HP'
  },
  {
    marca: 'Chevrolet',
    modelo: 'Camaro',
    especificacion: 'Velocidad: 250 km/h'
  },
  {
    marca: 'Chevrolet',
    modelo: 'Camaro',
    especificacion: 'Cilindrada: 3700 cc'
  },
  {
    marca: 'Chevrolet',
    modelo: 'Camaro',
    especificacion: 'Peso: 1580 Kg'
  },
  {
    marca: 'Dodge',
    modelo: 'Charger',
    especificacion: 'Potencia: 320 HP'
  },
  {
    marca: 'Dodge',
    modelo: 'Charger',
    especificacion: 'Velocidad: 230 km/h'
  },
  {
    marca: 'Dodge',
    modelo: 'Charger',
    especificacion: 'Cilindrada: 3900 cc'
  },
  {
    marca: 'Dodge',
    modelo: 'Charger',
    especificacion: 'Peso: 1800 Kg'
  }
]
```

no es que no cumpla su cometido pero lo que yo desearia obtener es un formato de salida como este:

```
[
  {
    marca: 'Ford',
    modelo: 'Mustang',
    especificaciones:[{especificacion: 'Potencia: 350 HP'},
                      {especificacion: 'Velocidad: 255 km/h'},
                      {especificacion: 'Cilindrada: 3500 cc'},
                      {especificacion: 'Peso: 1340 Kg'}
                     ]
  },
  {
    marca: 'Chevrolet',
    modelo: 'Camaro',
    especificaciones:[{especificacion: 'Potencia: 345 HP'},
                      {especificacion: 'Velocidad: 250 km/h'},
                      {especificacion: 'Cilindrada: 3700 cc'},
                      {especificacion: 'Peso: 1580 Kg'}
                     ]
  },
  {
    marca: 'Dodge',
    modelo: 'Charger',
    especificaciones:[{especificacion: 'Potencia: 320 HP'},
                      {especificacion: 'Velocidad: 230 km/h'},
                      {especificacion: 'Cilindrada: 3900 cc'},
                      {especificacion: 'Peso: 1800 Kg'}
                     ]
  }
]
```

el cual es mucho mas practico de usar que el anterior.

La cuestión es: ¿Puedo obtener una salida como la ultima modificando las sentencias `TSQL` o hay que trabajar el objeto resultante con `JS` para obtener la salida deseada?

He intentado con las otras 2 sentencias `TSQL`.

La segunda da un error ya que no se puede tener mas de un valor para una subconsulta.

La tercera me entrega marca modelo y especificaciones como objeto `JS` y el arreglo de especificaciones en formato `JSON`, lo cual no me sirve.

Se que a la tercera podría ponerle un `JSON Path` en la consulta principal y me entregaría todo en formato `JSON` lo cual podría luego convertir a objeto `JS` con `JSON.parse()` pero este ejemplo es una muestra y en la base de datos real los `JSONs` son mucho mas complejos y en `NODE` no obtengo buenos resultados con consultas que vengan en formato `JSON` desde `SQL Server` (lo raro es que la misma consulta desde `Management Studio` con salida `JSON` si es correcta, y al ejecutarla desde `MSSQL/NODE` el `JSON` resultante tiene errores).

Hace varios días que estoy peleando con esto, si alguien puede ayudarme seria fantástico.

Comment: Hernán, espero que estes muy bien.  No entiendo la pregunta concretamente, queres saber si se puede lograr el ultimo `Json` directamente desde una consulta `mssql`? o queres saber la lógica a implementar para formatear la respuesta de `getEmbarque` como en el ultimo `Json`?

Comment: @Martín Fernandez, Gracias por tu interes, ya pude resolverlo, slds!!